# Stop prompting for credentials / remember windows authentication for TFS 2015

Tags: iis, tfs, windows-authentication

Our TFS 2015 application tier has 3 bindings:

1. A http binding, using the domain name of the server
2. A https binding, using self signed certificate mapped to an alias (cname) of the fqdn of the server
3. A https binding, using a certificate mapped to a dns that is accessible outside of our network.

When accessing the application the first time using either one of the first two bindings, a prompt for entering credentials shows up. After entering the correct credentials, the prompt does not appear anymore, and the authentication is done automatically every time.

But when trying to access the application using the third binding, the prompt shows up every time, and it even shows up in the middle of using the web site, making it a pain to use it.

More info:
The web site is hosted on IIS 8.5.
The tfs application of the Team Foundation Website uses only Windows Authentication with NTLM.

Comment: Did you use some proxy in way3?

Answer (score 0):

To connect TFS  server outside of your network.There are three ways (at least) to address this, you can give a try with another way to see if the issue is gone:

- Public IP Addresses -- this means that you would give your TFS Server
  public IP addresses.  This means you would need static IP addresses
  from your ISP.  You would also generally use NAT and access lists to
  allow that traffic into your network (though you could do public
  itself, but that is a huge security risk.)  You would also need to
  register the name resolution with a public DNS provider.
- Use DDNS -- this is similar, but that you would not need the static
  addresses.  Most home routers today allow you to subscribe to paid
  DDNS services that let you use normal assigned IP addresses and have
  the DNS map to this.  Most of these services handle DNS for you so
  you don't have to do the extra work.
- Set up a VPN connection.  This will allow you to create a tunnel
  between networks so that his machine can hit your server.  Normally
  this requires statis IP addresses but there are some services out
  there that can help you.